# xpath to identify unique element

Tags: xml, xpath

This question might reflect my stark ignorance on Xpath knowledge but I still dare to ask it.
I have my xml structure that goes something  in similar to this:

```
<record>
<data>
<type>student</type>
<name>Kevin</name>
</data>

<data>
<type>teacher</type>
<name>Matt</name>
</data>
</record>
```

How do I write xpath to select Matt, the teacher? Does "//record/data/name" always return the first/last/all/unguaranteed record it matches?

Thanks
Kevin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`//record/data/name` will match both `name` elements in your example XML.

To match the teacher specifically, you should add a predicate:

`/record/data[type='teacher']/name`

If you had more than one "teacher" it would match all of them. You could narrow it further though...

This would match the first teacher:

`(/record/data[type='teacher']/name)[1]`

This would match the first teacher named "Matt":

`(/record/data[type='teacher']/name[.='Matt'])[1]`

Answer (score 0):

```
/record/data[type='teacher']/name
```

**[X-path Syntax](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_syntax.asp)**